# I want to replace a media file (pdf) with an updated version

Tags: uploads, media

I have an updated version of a pdf file which is linked to several pages and pending posts. I want to replace the old version with the new one and keep all the existing links.
Thank
Priya

Comment: there is also a plugin called WXY Tools Media Replace that is easier to use and works anywhere you can upload an attachment. It also preserves any alternate text, descriptions, or categories for attachments. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use this plugin [Enable Media Replace](http://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-media-replace/)

Simply install it then you will be able to replace media items with new ones.

It will also give you the option to keep the existing file name or update all links with the new filename.

Comment: Hi Mark Thanks for that; however I seem to have lost a lot of the images on my site. Is that pure coincidence or has the plugin caused this? Thanks

Comment: I've never seen such an issue with it worth checking out https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/enable-media-replace to see if anyone else has. Have you got any caching plugins or anything that might be causing conflicts with it changing stuff?

Answer (score 3):

You have acesss to FTP/ Wordpress Files ? This is quite a simple: Take a look on the URL of your PDF. It should look like thi:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/(month you have uploaded this file)/(day)/yourfile.pdf
```

Just follow this path on your Wordpress files and replace the old pdf with the new pdf and make sure the new pdf have the same name of the older. ( replace it )

Comment: Unless you've changed the paths of course